# REST API - File moved - Origin server relative url

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, getchanges

When a file is moved in SharePoint, I can catch the event using the GetChanges API.

```
_api/web/lists('listid')/GetChanges
```

My issue is that I need to retrieve the **origin** and **destination** server relative url of the file.
I tried to retrieve all the details of the item (+file) but I'm not able to retrieve the origin, I only have the destination url. Here is the call I'm doing:

```
_api/web/lists('listid')/items(11)?$expand=file/versions
```

The version of the file is not updated when a file is moved so I cannot get the origin path from there.

**Update 1**

I have find a way to retrieve the server relative url of all the changes using

```
_api/web/lists('listid')/RootFolder/GetListItemChanges?$filter=ItemId eq 19
```

But when a file is deleted, this call returns an empty list. I want to still have these information even if the file is deleted.